# nginx blacklist outgoing traffic from my web server

Tags: nginx

I have nginx deployed as a proxy running in front of a puma web server.
What I would like to do is to block outgoing traffic to certain domains.

In the following scenario I'm trying to prevent my app from contacting example.com. Can I have nginx listening on the same socket file, for the blacklist block, so I can see the request from my web server ? As with this current setup its not working.

Here is my config:

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/tmp/nginx.socket fail_timeout=0;
}

#Block outgoing to this domain
server {
    listen <%= ENV["PORT"] %>;
    server_name  example.com;
    return 404;
}

server {
    listen <%= ENV["PORT"] %>;
    server_name _;
    keepalive_timeout 5;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;

    }
}
```

to be more specific my application is hosted and I have no access to firewalls or hosts files. Nginx is my only option for now and my web server is binded to unix:/tmp/nginx.socket

Comment: Is `example.com` pointed to `127.0.0.1` in your hosts file?

Comment: To be more specific this is running in Heroku so my solution is hosted and I have not control over traffic, firewalls, .. etc. but to use nginx. So what I would like to do for example is prevent my app from sending out a requests to google.com and return 404.

Comment: nginx is not making the requests so why are you trying to stop it there?

Comment: @ShawnC. thats what im trying to figure out, a way to let nginx block outgoing requests from my web server.

Comment: nginx isn't what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone needed such a solution were access or options, in a hosting environment, are limited. Based on the environment our application is hosted in, here is how I was able to achieve a "forward proxy" solution, as a part of my overall reverse proxy.

Simply requests from my application to the internet will go through a standalone/solo nginx first and based on what I define as a "whitelist" in my second block it will determine if thats allowed or not.

```
# simple reverse proxy 
 server {
   listen <%= ENV["PORT"] %>;
   server_name _;
   keepalive_timeout 5;
   client_max_body_size <%= ENV['NGINX_CLIENT_MAX_BODY_SIZE'] || 1 %>M;

   location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/
   }
 }

  ## FORWARD PROXY ##

  # iterate over the WHITELIST var
  map $http_host $outbound {
    default deny;
    <% ENV['WHITELIST'].split(" ").each do |url| %>
      ~\s*<%= url %>$ allow;
    <% end %>
  } 

  # applications connect internally to nginx using port 80 and not directly to the public network
  server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
      if ( $outbound = "deny" ) { return 403; }
      resolver 8.8.8.8;
      proxy_pass http://$http_host$request_uri;
    }
  }
```

This is the general approach and my config will have more rules and options used based on our application needs. Someone might argue that nginx may or may not be utilized for such purpose but when options are limited especially when using PaaS this was a good approach.